# Ruby. Gsub single slash combinations \& \' \+ \0

Tags: ruby-2.0

```
   bang=[]
    (33..126).each{|x| bang<<x.chr}
    block=bang.repeated_permutation(2) 

for i in 1..8836
       x=block.next.join
       if not "x".gsub("x",x).size==2
          puts x 
       end 
    end
```

OUTPUT=>

```
   \&
    \'
    \+
    \0
    \1
    \2
    \3
    \4
    \5
    \6
    \7
    \8
    \9
    \\
    \`
```

So. Here is a. Little script that shows the special characters that cause gsub to fail... I hope to find a solution to get gsub to work 100%

Comment: try to write in simple words what is the problem. so people know what your code is all about.

Answer (score 0):

It is [documented](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-sub) that `sub` and `gsub` handles sequences like '\1' in the replacement string a special way:

> If replacement is a String it will be substituted for the matched
>   text. It may contain back-references to the pattern’s capture groups
>   of the form "\d", where d is a group number, or "\k", where n is a
>   group name.

You can use `sub` and `gsub` in block style. The block need to return the string that should be the substitution.

```
"x".sub("x"){|match| '\1'}
=> '\1'    # or outputted as "\\1"

"x".sub("x"){|match| '\1'}.size
=> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

here was my solution to this problem... if any one runs into this same thing.

```
    puts "ruby rules !".gsub("!"){"\\&"}=>
   #ruby rules \& 
   #ruby rules \' 
   #ruby rules \+ 
   #ruby rules \0 
   #ruby rules \1 
   #ruby rules \2 
   #ruby rules \3 
   #ruby rules \4 
   #ruby rules \5 
   #ruby rules \6 
   #ruby rules \7 
   #ruby rules \8 
   #ruby rules \9 
   #ruby rules \\ 
   #ruby rules \`
```